# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'

Tags: php

please I'm new to web developing and PHP programming as well, I've a PHP form code and a form but whenever i test it on a server this the error message I get:

> FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE or     '$' on line number 18

And the code follows:

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "test@mail.com";
/* Check all form inputs using check_input
function */
$yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'],
"Enter your name");
$subject  = check_input($_POST['subject'],
"Write a subject");
$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$website  = check_input($_POST['website']);
$likeit   = check_input($_POST['likeit']);
$how_find = check_input($_POST['how']);
$comments = check_input($_POST['comments'],
"Write your comments");
/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $
email))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}
/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/
i", $website))
{
$website = '';
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!
Your contact form has been submitted by:
Name: $yourname
E-mail: $email
URL: $website
Like the website? $likeit
How did he/she find it? $how_find
Comments:
$comments
End of message
";
/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);
/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thanks.html');
exit();
/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
    show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}
function show_error($myError)
{

<html>
<body>
<b>Please correct the following error:</b>
<br />
 echo $myError; 
</body>
</html>

exit();
}
```

Comment: on line 18 you got email, put in on the line before

Comment: Thanks a lot form working now, sad I missed that line though, should have used a programming IDE instead to bypass this blur. SALUTE !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a redundant (read: wrong) line-break between `$` and `email`. Replace:

```
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $
email))
```

with:

```
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! buddy  , problem solved . Was utterly confused though.